# Create a keycloak custom registration flow

Tags: keycloak, user-registration

Is there any possibility to configure custom registration flows in keycloak? I want to integrate a SMS OTP validation after the user fills the registration form and submit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can copy the default registration flow and modify it to your needs (add authenticators for OTP etc.)

[image: Default Registration Flow]

Afterwards change the authentication flow bindings to your newly created registration flow.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir, I also want to Add same OTP validation when user sign up through the social media (google/facebook) also, is that possible to extend the flow with OTP integration?

Comment: Yes, in that case you need to adjust the "first broker login" flow and assign it in your IdP configuration (facebook/google). If you need OTP with every login, use the "post login flow" instead.

Comment: Sir, is there any possibility to modify the "first broker login" and "registration" flows to create the user only when the OTP validations succeed?, at the moment when we go to the OTP page user is created in keycloak.

Comment: I don't think so. For OTP validation the user needs to register an authenticator app with the account. So, the account needs to exist for this.

Comment: idPs have a 'post login flown'. i found this easier for some tasks then making a custom flow.

Comment: Sir, I have used the keycloak standalone version for my application, also I have developed and integrated some plugins and themes as well to it. Now I want to dockerize this version. How I can proceed with that? Is it possible to get keycloak docker version and integrate the new plugins and Themes or do I need to build from this standalone version?

Comment: I would recommend that you add a new question for this.